# React Native API data fetch and save as global data

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am new to React Native. I am creating a simple app that has a Drawer Navigation. After login I want to update user Name and Email on the Drawer. I tried to fetch the the data from API using `fetch()` in the `ComponentDidMount()` method, but the problem is when I am setting the data in state it has some promise error.

I want to know the better approach to fetch the data from API and store it so that it can be accessible in any component, usually the auth token and email of the user.

Also anyone suggest a better way to maintain the code with API fetching, I am writing the code for fetch in every component so it become cluttered everywhere.

Update Code:

```
export class CustomDrawer extends React.Component{
 state = {
      token: '',
      id: '',
      user: '',
 }
 componentDidMount = async() =>{
    await this.getAll();
 }

 setMyToken = () => {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken').then((value) =>{
   let temp = JSON.parse(value)
   this.setState({token : temp.token})
 }

 getAll = async() => {
  await this.setMyToken();
  return fetch(`API_URL`).then(response=>response.text().then(text=>{
  const data = text && JSON.parse(text)
  this.setState({user: data.username,  id: data.id})
 })).catch(function(error){
     console.log(error)
 });
 }

}
```

Comment: You're doing the right thing. There could be a syntax error here. Try posting the code here. Also, official documentation for fetch : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks

Comment: code added.. If I do the setMyToken() in componentDidMount() and then call the function getAll() on button click everything works fine, but when I try to load both of then automatically, it shows error.

Comment: call setMyToken() method in componentDidMount()  and on Async then() method call getAll() method with params like getAll(JSON.parse(value)) and u got your value in getAll () method  and also remove return in getAll() why you need that ?

Comment: @AnkitPatel Hey thanks! It worked.. got the data but now it shows the warning: can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component.